# Need help solving for PSIG

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm trying to find PSIG from other variables that I have values for. I'll try my best to explain.

I have Helium flowing through a 1" copper pipe at 65 psig and at 40 deg F to a 1" ball valve and power control valve. There is a flow meter connected after the power control valve, with the ball valve throttled to achieve 40 CFM. I need to find the PSIG after the throttled ball valve.

I'm looking for the formula or a web calculator to solve this equation. I don't need a precise answer, just a rounded.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks, Steve.

[image]

Comment: One hint ; the flow rate and pipe size implies a velocity, which suggests you can use Bernoulli's Eqn

Comment: The answer depends completely on what is downstream of the point where it says "? PSIG".  With the current information, the only possible answer is that it's not more than 65 psig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for all of us who have to deal with fluid mechanics, pressure drop through a valve from a flow rate can't be computed without knowing the Cv of the valve. You actually need the Cv of both valves here. From that, and knowing your target flow rate, you can compute how much the pressure will need to drop to achieve the flow rate.

You can work the problem the other way, too: have a fixed pressure at the outlet and work backwards to find what your flow rate will be. Either way, you need the Cv or the pressure.

There are a million different references out there on valve sizing and the relevant equations: my personal favorite is "Fluid Flow Basics of Throttling Valves": http://www.controlglobal.com/assets/Media/MediaManager/RefBook_Cashco_Fluid.pdf

The equation you want, for gas flow, is:

```
Cv = Qdot / (N7 * Fp * P1 * Y) * sqrt(Mw * T1 * Z1 / X)
```

With:

```
Qdot - volumetric flow rate in SCFH
N7 - Unit correlation constant = 1360
Fp - Piping geometry factor (can be taken as 1 for your case)
P1 - Absolute upstream pressure in psia
Y - Expansion factor (maximum of 1, minimum of 0.667 - plug both in to get a range of possible pressures)
Mw - molecular weight in lb/lb mole
T1 - Temperature in Rankine
Z1 - compressibility factor 
X - Pressure drop ratio (i.e., (UpstreamP - DownstreamP) / UpstreamP)
```

So clearly here you need to either solve for X given Cv and Qdot, or Cv given X and Qdot...and probably now you can see why this can end up being someone's full time job.

Answer (score 0):

The pressure downstream valve can be any value less than 65psig.

If downstream pressure at 60psig, valve maybe fully open. If downstream pressure at 0psig, valve maybe only slightly open.

Theoretically, pressure downstream valve will be 65psig - pressure drop between Pressure Gauge to inlet valve - pressure drop of valve at current opening.